# How to customize the WordPress 2014 theme, to have page using less horizontal margin?

Tags: customization, themes, css, child-theme

How do I customize the WordPress 2014 theme, to have a single pages content use less horizontal margin?

Do I need to create a custom theme?  Or is there a simple way to modify or customize the theme that I missed?

Below, I have a large image left aligned which does not leave too much horizontal space for the image.   It's a requirement that the the image be the size that currently is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with some Customized CSS, which you an insert via the Theme Customization, Additional CSS area.

Use developer tools (press F12, or right-click the area and use Inspect Element) to see the CSS class used for the area you want to modify. Then use different `margin` or `padding` to position things.